# Django ManyToManyField - Causes error on record create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So Im essentially joining two tables using a manyTomanyField. Everything works well until I go to my admin page to create some test data.
I get an error which reads below:

```
invalid input syntax for type bigint: "John97"
LINE 1: ...ducers_producer_product_categories"."producer_id" = 'John97'
```

Where "John97" is the pk of one table, which is a OneToOneField relating to another table with a pk of type CharField. For context, the second table in my manyTomany relation also has a pk of type CharField.
It seems to me like Django is attempting to save my pk as a BigInt in the through table and is running into problems. My question is, why is this happening and how do I stop it? I would like to keep my pk as a OneToOneField with my User table, so if there is an alternative Im all ears!
Models:

```
    class Producer(models.Model):
    #Model describes the table for producer profiles
    userID = models.OneToOneField('Users.User',on_delete=CASCADE,primary_key=True)                                              #ID of producer (Links to USer Table)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,default='New')                                                      #Description of buyer profile
    prof_img = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,default=' ')                                                          #Profile Image of producer
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                                                               #Describes whether producer is verified or not (Farmers license etc.)
    delivery_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                                                        #Describes whether producer is delivering or not
    delivery_fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places=2,default=0.00)                                           #Describes any delivery fees incured on producer
    delivery_distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places=2,default=25.00)                                      #Describes maximum distance of delivery for producer
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=0)                                                      #Producer overall rating out of 5
    number_ratings = models.IntegerField(default=0)                                                                             #Number of orders rated for producer
    last_inventory_update = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Time stamp of last inventory update',auto_now_add=True)          #Last time producer updated inventory
    online_status = models.BooleanField(default = False)                                                                        #Describes if producer is online or not.(Orders cannot be placed for offline producers)
    product_categories = models.ManyToManyField('Products.Category',related_name='category',blank=True)                         #What categories producers produce
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.userID.__str__()
    
    #Function calculates and sets rating of producer 
    def calculateRating(self,rating):
        totalDouble = self.number_ratings * self.rating
        self.rating = self.rating + 1
        newDouble = totalDouble + rating
        finalRating = newDouble / self.number_ratings
        self.rating = finalRating

class User(models.Model):
    #Model describes base user table. All users extend the base user table
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)                                               #ID of User
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                            #User first name
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                             #User last name
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                              #Organisation name of user
    email_address = models.EmailField()                                                                     #Email Address of user
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                                             #Phone number of user
    device_tokens = ArrayField(                                                                             #Tokens of user device for notification sending
        models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True),null=True,blank=True
    )
    current_location = models.OneToOneField('Locations.Location', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)             #Linking of Current Location for user (Links to locations table)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org_name

class Category(models.Model):
    #Model describes categories of product
    categoryID = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)              #ID of category.
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)                             #Name of category
    category_img = models.CharField(max_length=200)                             #Image of category
    category_alt_img = models.CharField(max_length=50)                          #Alt text for category img

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

TraceBack:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Producers/producer/add/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_extensions',
 'Users',
 'Locations.apps.LocationsConfig',
 'Products.apps.ProductsConfig',
 'Inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',
 'Cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'Orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
 'Buyers',
 'Producers.apps.ProducersConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (invalid input syntax for type bigint: "John97"
LINE 1: ...ducers_producer_product_categories"."producer_id" = 'John97'
                                                               ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1657, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1587, in _changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1125, in save_related
    form.save_m2m()
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 451, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1668, in save_form_data
    getattr(instance, self.attname).set(data)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1000, in set
    old_ids = set(self.using(db).values_list(self.target_field.target_field.attname, flat=True))
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 171, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1130, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Alick\OneDrive\Documents\Ceres-Server\ceres\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /admin/Producers/producer/add/
Exception Value: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "John97"
LINE 1: ...ducers_producer_product_categories"."producer_id" = 'John97'
```

Edit: Seems to be some migration conflict. Previously my pks were autogenerated ints handled by django. I changed my pk to my OneToOneField and there must have been some mixup in migrations. I had the exact same error with another model, so I deleted all migration files and reset my db, and now the other model works fine. This one still raises the error tho.

Comment: Please share the relevant models, the view where the error is raised, and the *full* traceback.

Comment: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "John97" the hint is in the error. "John97" is a string, it's expecting an integer. Please clarify the question like Willem has stated. It's unclear what is going on here, mainly because this is the sort of thing the ORM would handle, yet it seems you're using raw SQL. Without an understanding of what you're trying to achieve we cannot help you

Comment: Ive included all relevant models and traceback. Im not using raw sql anywhere. Hope it can clarify things a bit.

Answer (score -1):

I seemed to have fixed it. The error was due to a problem in migrations.
Previously my models used auto-generated integers as primary keys. I later changed to using my OneToOneField as their primary keys which point to a CharField. Something went wrong in migration and django tried to access my table by the BigInt type and not the new CharField type.

Steps to Fix:

1. Reset database using reset_db command from [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package: `python manage.py reset_db`
2. Delete all migration files for all modules. (You may be able to get away with deleting a few if you keep better track of your migrations than me. I deleted everything just to be safe)
3. Make migrations and migrate everything, create a new super user: Success!`python manage.py makemigrations` `python manage.py migrate` `python manage.py createsuperuser`